# Retrieving data from Firebase with Google UID

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database for my Android app structured as follows:

```
Users
  UserUID
    Data
  UserUID
    Data
```

Because some of the users authenticated with email and password, their uids are of the form `9c16720b-f827-4216-b9f1-a3fa2c311633`.

Other users authenticated with Google and their uids are of the form `google:106458782077325555555`.

I am trying to query the data by using this code:

```
private void setupFirebaseQuery() {
    String location = mFirebaseRef.child("users/" + mFirebaseRef.getAuth().getUid()).toString();
    Log.d("LOCATION", location);
    mQuery = new Firebase(location);
}
```

This data is then passed to a custom adapter that extends [this implementation](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/matteo/firebase_recycleview/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
    mAdapter = new FirebaseDataListAdapter(mQuery, Data.class);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I know the adapter works because data is retrieved and displayed fine - except for users that authenticated with Google. For those users no data is retrieved or displayed.

I don't think this is a permissions issue in Firebase because I have temporarily set read and write to true. I've also tried going to the logged url in a browser and it successfully retrieves data for the relevant user, even those who logged in with google. The logged url does convert the `:` in the uid to a `%3A` but that seems like expected behavior.

Does anyone have any ideas why this successfully retrieves data for email/password users but not Google users?

Comment: "The logged url does convert the : in the uid to a %3A but that seems like expected behavior." You'll need to decode that %3A when you construct a `new Firebase(location)`. But why are you converting to a string and back like that. Can't you just say `mQuery = mFirebaseRef.child("users/" + mFirebaseRef.getAuth().getUid())`?

Comment: Thanks - I did try setting the location string to be `mFirebaseRef.child("users/" + mFirebaseRef.getAuth().getUid()).toString()` but that didn't work. Your suggested approach does work though. Thanks for the help. I didn't realize you could assign a child to a query directly like that. It's also good to know that the url character would need to be decoded.